# draw overlay line on google static map with markers

Tags: google-maps, overlay, google-maps-markers

i used this url to draw map with overlay line

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&zoom=13&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&sensor=false

i want to add markers to start and end position..
so i used the url below

[maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&zoom=13&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&sensor=false](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&zoom=13&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aS|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&sensor=false)

this url shows markers but not the overlay line..

please give me the url to overlay roadmap on static googlemap image with markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&zoom=13&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aS|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&sensor=false

Your path lat/lng is missing from the second link

Comment: Is it possible to draw a "Road Path" alone roads?