# I want to draw staight line between origin and destination using static google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps

i am developing an android app, i want to draw a staight line between 2 point by giving those points... i want to use static google map as picture format. there is an option to draw PolyLine but that takes lots of points to join them. i have only 2 points origin and destination(Latitute and Longitute).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [draw overlay line on google static map with markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166408/draw-overlay-line-on-google-static-map-with-markers)

Answer (score 0):

```
PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(point1, point2));
mGoogleMap.addPolyline(line);
```

i.e. Just add the 2 points to PolylineOptions and add the PolylineOptions to google map.
Beside adding the points you can do various customizations to the line like line color, pattern, etc as explained in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial#add_a_polyline_to_draw_a_line_on_the_map

Comment: thats for dynamic google maps. i am asking about static google map...
https://staticmapmaker.com/google/ maybe this website can help you to understand my question. the website provide option for adding markers and some other properties but not the path.